# what happend re-define setInterval to variable in useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

I want to know what happened if I define setInterval function repeatedly to same variable in react hook useEffect.

I checked variable have new setInterval id value every defining.
But I wonder is there instance remained in memory about previous setInterval timer, even if new setInterval defined at same variable??

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(
      () => {
        if (count < elementLength - 1) {
          boolean.current = false;
          setCount(prev => prev + 1);
        } else {
          boolean.current = true;
          setCount(0);
        }
      },
      boolean.current ? 50 : 2500
    );

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [count]);
```

Comment: Which variable do you mean, `timer`?

Comment: Each time count changes, useEffect is called and the previous timer is removed.

Comment: @Bergi yes, timer!! thanks for your comment. please tell me your ideas...

Comment: @mahan Oh, that means setInterval timer having "current - 1" id value is removed from memory??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens if I assign repeatedly to same variable?

It's not the *same* variable. It's creating a fresh new `timer` variable every time the effect runs. They're all independent.

> But I wonder is there instance remained in memory about previous `timer`

Yes and no. The cleanup function returned by the `useEffect` callback is a closure over the `timer`, and it is kept in memory by React as long as necessary. In practice, it will be called once when the component unmounts or its dependencies change, and can be garbage-collected afterwards, taking with it the respective `timer` variable.

Comment: Thanks.
That's for changing interval time in specific situation(boolean.current false or true) why i'm insert 'count' React state to dependency array.
But as you know, that makes garbage-collected repeatedly.
-
-
Could you suggest me, how to change interval time in the specific condition (such as 'count' === 0)?

Comment: You can literally use `count === 0` as a dependency.